# Rotary Encoder problem with LCD Display

Tags: lcd, rotary-encoder, debounce

Program reads rotary encoder correctly without bouncing in this code:

```
int val = 0;
byte clkPin = 3;
byte dtPin = 2;
bool lastClk;
bool lastDt;
void setup() {
  pinMode(clkPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(dtPin,INPUT);
  lastClk = digitalRead(3);
  lastDt = digitalRead(2);
  val = 0;
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(clkPin), clkRise, RISING);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
}

void clkRise(){
      lastClk = HIGH;
      lastDt = digitalRead(dtPin);
      if(lastDt == LOW){
        val--;
        Serial.println(val);
        }  else{val++; Serial.println(val);}
        }
```

but when i use lcd to show the result, i get massive bounces (i think) in this code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#include <Wire.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);
int val = 0;
byte clkPin = 3;
byte dtPin = 2;
bool lastClk;
bool lastDt;
void setup() {
  lcd.begin();
  pinMode(clkPin,INPUT);
  pinMode(dtPin,INPUT);
  lastClk = digitalRead(3);
  lastDt = digitalRead(2);
  val = 0;
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(clkPin), clkRise, RISING);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.home();
}

void loop() {
  lcd.print(val);
}

void clkRise(){
      lastClk = HIGH;
      lastDt = digitalRead(dtPin);
      if(lastDt == LOW){
        val--;
        Serial.println(val);
        }  else{val++;}
        }
```

it increases and decreases by random numbers between 0-5.I use KY-040 R.E. it has built-in 10k pull up resistors.

This is what i use to debounce:

```
A or B pin of R.E--10k R----------------------------------Arduino INPUT PIN
                         |
                         |
                         =0.1uF C
                         |
                         ---------------------GND
```

Comment: Try adding a slight delay after `lcd.print(val);`. Something like `delay(50);`. Also, if the R.E. has in internal pull-up of 10k, the series resistor between the A/B pin should be lower than 10k. Otherwise the maximum voltage is only 2.5V (Vcc/2).

Comment: @Gerben i tried delaying, it works better but there are still big jumps like 3-4+

Comment: Either increase the delay, or only do the lcd.print if the value of `val` has changed.

Comment: @Gerben it work way better now, but there are still rare jumps. would a schmitt trigger fix this? I took off the 10k resistor that i placed.

Comment: I don't know. That's not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that your hardware-debounce capacitive circuit isn't working well enough to accurately debounce the contacts, and that invalid transitions are occurring on the quadrature lines as read by the program.

Note that use of `Serial.println()` within your `clkRise()` interrupt handler is problematic, because `Serial.println()` uses interrupts itself. As far as I know, `println()` is not reentrant, ie cannot be used correctly from the multiple interrupts that may start before previous `println()` calls finish their background processing.  The bits of extra delay introduced by LCD code may merely be exposing a problem.

There is no need for either hardware or software debouncing on quadrature inputs.  A correctly-implemented state machine will reject invalid conditions that arise during bounce, or will immediately follow any extra up-tick by a corresponding down-tick, or vice versa.

For some state machine code, see for example [answer 16420/3917](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/16420/3917) and also see [answer 18221/3917](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/18221/3917).  Also see [answer 19109/3917](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/19109/3917).

Comment: Çay Öncesi should definitely **not** be doing `Serial.println` inside an ISR.

Comment: @NickGammon alright. I finished my project. just curious, what is the outcome of placing Serial.println inside an ISR?

Comment: Serial.print puts whatever-it-is you want to print into a buffer. It then waits for interrupts to empty the buffer. If the buffer is full already, it waits *before* putting data into the buffer. Since the buffer won't be emptied inside an ISR, if the serial buffer is full, the program will then block indefinitely.

Comment: What I've been doing in my decoder interrupt routines is to set a "valueChanged" flag. Then in the app's main loop, if value changed is true, I use Serial.println() to print it and set `valueChanged=false`. That way I'm not trying to do serial.print inside an ISR. When I needed more info than that. I created a large (`char logBuffer[100]`) C string to contain my logged data, and used `strcat()` to append to that. Then in the app's loop() I print the logBuffer and set it back to empty.

Comment: @DuncanC, the general idea of using a buffer like that is ok, but there are several races that can occur -- eg if the ISR adds to the buffer between loop()'s "print the logBuffer" and its "set it back to empty" operations, the added data gets lost.  One can fix the problems using semaphores, or switching between two buffers atomically, etc